# C++ int main(int argc, char* argv[]) arguments usage problem

Tags: c++-cli

The common language runtime support is set to (/clr). When I try to write(display) the argument argv[1] nothing happens. Any help please. Compilation warning states- forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Console::WriteLine(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code, please edit your question to include the code you have problems with.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns true"?

Comment: int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 Console::WriteLine(argv[1]);
}

Comment: Im sorry Joachim and Kiril my code is not legible, kindly advice on how do I make it aligned proper, thanks

Comment: @user2982029 Please put your code in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Joachim and Kiril thats how the code is, please

Comment: I have a feeling that `WriteLine` doesn't have an overload for pointers, and that the `bool` overload is the closest match.

Comment: @molbdnilo , sure but then I thought argv was of char* and so that should have been displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no [`Console::WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console.WriteLine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function taking a `char*`. You should convert it to a `String` object.

Regarding the warning message and the output, it's because since the compiler can't find an exact match for the `WriteLine` call, it will, if possible, pick another function. In this case it picks the one taking a `Boolean` argument, because pointers can implicitly be converted to `bool` which in turn can be converted to `Boolean`. The output is `"true"` because any non-null pointer is considered true in a pointer-to-bool conversion.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, you are right.  A simple printf was also something that could have given me the string in it